# Структура android-приложения

Tags: android, архитектура

Мне надо сделать android-приложение, где будет обращение к api и последовательный вывод этого в RecycleView. Основным моментом является использование clean architecture. Прошу подсказки какие классы должны быть в моей проекте и за что отвечать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Расписывать всю архитектуру приложения здесь это очень много. Ваша задача разбить приложение не модули. Можете посмотреть в сторону архитектурного паттерна MVP. Следуя ему вы сможете отделить логику приложения от его интерфейса. 
Неплохой пример реализации MVP можно найти здесь. https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/493-mvp-dlja-nachinajuschih-bez-bibliotek-i-interfejsov.html
https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/473-mvp-na-primere-jekrana-s-pin-kodom.html

Так же можете посмотреть на библиотеку Moxy, она упрощает некоторые моменты, но я бы не рекомендовал ее без понимания основ MVP.